# how to charge images in pgm format in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning

Hello I'm using the CMU Face Images Data Set https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/CMU+Face+Images to build a model that allows me to recognize subjects who wear sunglasses, these images are in pgm format, I'm very new in machine learning and I do not know how to read the images in R.
Does anyone know in what way I can do it? and if you have any recommendation for the construction of the model, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826051/read-pnm-error-trying-to-read-pgm-image) to read a pgm image.

```
x=read.pnm(file = "Aaron_Guiel_0001.pgm")
```