# Not able to use the readImage function in R

Tags: r

I have downloaded the latest R package and am using RStudio and am trying to convert a pgm image into a csv file and am using a readImage function.
Although any time I do
`img <- readImage(file)`
where file is the filepath

I get

`Error in readImage(file) : could not find function "readImage"`

Is there some other pack I need to download or am I using it wrong?

Comment: There are literally thousands of R packages, and only a few come bundled with R. None of these include a function called `readImage`. There is a package available called `OpenImageR` that has a function called `readImage`, though I don't know if it handles pgm format. To try it, you need to do `install.packages("OpenImageR")` then, once it is installed, `library(OpenImageR)`. Then try your code again.

Comment: In fact, I have just tried it, and it does not suport pgm

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/12826051/4752675

Comment: @AllanCameron Is there perhaps another function that you would know that can handle reading pgm files? I have tried read.pnm but i get a ```Error in file(file, open = "rb") : invalid 'description' argument```

Comment: @Iluvatar546 yes, check out my answer. As with many image manipulation tasks, the `magick` package is very useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `magick` package to read `pgm` files.

First, you need to do:

```r
install.packages("magick")
```

Now you call

```r
library(magick)
```

In my case, I have a `pgm` file in my R home directory, so I make the file path with:

```r
file <- path.expand("~/cat.pgm")
```

Now I can read the image and convert it into a matrix of RGB strings by doing:

```
img <- image_read(file)
ras <- as.raster(img)
mat <- as.matrix(ras)
```

To write this to csv format, I can do:

```
write.csv(mat, "cat.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

So now I have the image saved as a csv file. To read this back in, and prove it works, I can do:

```r
cat_csv <- read.csv("cat.csv")
cat_ras <- as.raster(as.matrix(cat_csv))
plot(cat_ras)
```

[image]

Note though that the csv file is very large - 9MB, which is one of the reasons why it is rarely a good idea to store an image as csv.

<sup>Created on 2022-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: this is great thanks! Although it doesn't seem to recognise my file paths, I'm getting

 ```Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip, defines) : 
  rsession.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `C:\Desktop\file_1.pgm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924```

I'm only converting very small images and I need to use matrix manipulation so a csv is alright for what I'm using it for

Comment: @Iluvatar546 that file doesn't exist. Try forward slashes in the file path, as backslashes are escape characters in R strings : `file <- "C:/Desktop/file_1.pgm"` and try the code again. (Obviously ensure the file is definitely there, spelled correctly etc too)